# "cropmarks"?? in Power Point

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I've received a presentation (.pptx) with strange marks around slides.

I've never seen anything similar in Power Point, what are those?

[image]

In the screenshot white part is the slide and grey is around them. Those marks appear around slides (inside ruler, not visible during presentation).

Comment: Is this fixed to the slides, or is there a background image that shows these? And do they show when you see the presentation, and do other elements align to them? (like guides) And can you move them?

Comment: @LPChip please see edit

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Following...

Comment: These are probably just normal drawn lines that someone has added to either the slide master or the layout that your slide is based on.  At a guess, it's to delineate where labels or some other type of repeated content will appear on the printed sheet.  Designers will put this kind of thing on the masters/layouts so that you don't accidentally select and move or delete them.